# Get the data from dynamic created Edittext

Tags: android, kotlin

i have created some dynamic textviews. I want to get the text of the textviews when the user clicks on the next button.
I have written the logic to create the  EditText in my Adapter class.
I have a button in my activity on Click of the button i want to fetch all the text from the text views that was created dynamically in my adapter class.

```
 if(input_type=="text")
    {
        holder.question.text=questionsList!![position].question
        val tableRow = TableRow(context)
        tableRow.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        var ansEditText = EditText(context)
        ansEditText.setPadding(5,5,5,15)
        ansEditText.setHint("Answer")
        ansEditText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
        ansEditText.textSize= 20F
        tableRow.addView(ansEditText)
        holder.linearQuestionanire.addView(tableRow)
      }
```

Comment: share the code for creating them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you have model something like Question.

One option is add field answer in to that model and add listener on your `EditText` `onTextChange()`, after text has changed save changes to your `Question.answer` field.
When using this approach you will have already mapped question-answer list.

Also `Pair<Question, Answer?>` is good use case I think

it might look something like this

```
  if (input_type == "text") {
            val question = questionsList!![position]
            holder.question.text = question.question
            val tableRow = TableRow(context)
            tableRow.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
            var ansEditText = EditText(context)
            ansEditText.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 15)
            ansEditText.setHint("Answer")
            ansEditText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
            ansEditText.textSize = 20F
            tableRow.addView(ansEditText)
            holder.linearQuestionanire.addView(tableRow)

            ansEditText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                    question.answer = s.toString()
                }

                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
                    // Empty
                }

                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                    // Empty
                }
            })
        }
```

also don't forget to remove `TextWatcher` so it would not cause memory leak

Comment: isn't  text from (first letter to end letter) not final text?

Comment: Also you can try to listen focus change of EditText and decide when input is finished, but this might be not so accurate

Comment: I'm able to get only the last editText value.Can i store the model that i'm creating in some array and then access the array from the activity

Comment: adapter has only reference of your list so basically what you editing in adapter should be edited inside the list also, when you press submit button just take all added values from primary questions/answers list

Comment: can i create a model class which can store the questions and ans in some key value pair and then get the values in my activity..???

Comment: Aš I mensioned in the answer you can use Pair

Comment: adapter has only reference of your list so basically what you editing in adapter should be edited inside the list also, when you press submit button just take all added values from primary questions/answers list –



I used this hint to solve my issue...Thank you..!!1

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you could approach this problem.

1. You could save the text in the textviews in a string array when you dynamically create them.
2. You could keep track of the textviews and get the text using `textView.getText()`.
3. You could keep track of the ids of the textviews, get the textview using 'findViewById()` and then get the text from the textview.

The most appropriate choice would obviously depend on your code, future considerations and other such criteria.